# Bukkit plugin - Listener not running?

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit, listeners

Hi I'm having this problem with my code everytime I make an object in a Listener class the listener won't work e.g.

I have this public variable in my main class (CSmain.java):

```
public static Location spawn;
```

I also have a method in that class called getSpawn() which returns spawn:

```
public Location getSpawn(){
    return spawn;
}
```

I have initialized the variable in my onEnable() but when I try to get it from my other class the class (JoinListener.java) won't work e.g.

```
@EventHandler
    public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event){

        CSmain mainClass = new CSmain();

        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("Worked");
        event.getPlayer().teleport(mainClass.getSpawn());
        event.getPlayer().setGameMode(GameMode.ADVENTURE);

        setItem(event.getPlayer(), Material.COMPASS, "§2§kll §a§lGAMES §2§kll", 0);

}
```

I have tested it without creating the object (CSmain mainClass = new CSmain();) and the (event.getPlayer().teleport(mainClass.getSpawn());) and the Listener works fine. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your main mod class, you should never make a new instance of it. Instead, you should have an

```
@Instance('yourmodid')
public static CSmain instance;
```

That way you can retrieve your mod instance from anywhere like so:

```
// assuming your getSpawn() returns chunk coordinates
ChunkCoordinates cc = CSmain.instance.getSpawn();
```

You can also get the world spawn position from event.entity.worldObj.getSpawn or getWorldSpawn - I can't remember off the top of my head and don't have code in front of me.

EDIT: I see your spawn 'Location' field is both public and static, meaning you can access it directly:

```
CSmain.location;
```

I urge you to read up on what the [static keyword](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-is-the-static-keyword-in-java.html) means, as it can majorly affect your code in unexpected ways if you do not completely understand it. Please do not use it just so you can easily access a field.